# How to hide duplicate rows and display 4 count texts in 4 columns

Tags: sql-server

I want to hide duplicate rows based on 2 columns (row,type)
In the status column I have 4 types of text
Enable,Disable,Run,End
Also 4 extra columns for these 4 texts
The number of each text based on that 2 columns is displayed in the corresponding column

I want to convert from :

```
|--------------------------------|
| id | row |value | type |status |
|--------------------------------|
| 1  | a   | a    |  a   |Enable |
| 2  | a   | a    |  a   |Disable|
| 3  | a   | a    |  a   |Run    |
| 4  | a   | a    |  a   |End    |
| 5  | a   | a    |  a   |End    |
|                                |
| 6  | a   | a    |  b   |Enable |
| 7  | a   | a    |  b   |Run    |
|                                |
| 8  | b   | a    |  b   |Enable |
| 9  | b   | a    |  b   |Disable|
|                                |
| 10 | b   | a    |  c   |Run    |
| 11 | b   | a    |  c   |End    |
| 12 | b   | a    |  c   |End    |
|                                |
| 13 | c   | a    |  a   |Enable |
| 14 | c   | a    |  a   |Run    |
|--------------------------------|
```

to :

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | row |value | type |status |number |Enable|Disable|Run|End|
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | a   | a    |  a   |Enable | 5     | 1    | 1     | 1 | 2 |
| 2  | a   | a    |  b   |Enable | 2     | 1    | 0     | 1 | 0 |
| 3  | b   | a    |  b   |Enable | 2     | 1    | 1     | 0 | 0 |
| 4  | b   | a    |  c   |Run    | 3     | 0    | 0     | 1 | 2 |
| 5  | c   | a    |  a   |Enable | 2     | 1    | 0     | 1 | 0 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

my query :

```sql
SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by min(id)) AS 'id'
      , row
      , MIN(value) AS 'value'
      , type
      , MIN(status) AS 'status'
      , COUNT(*) AS'number'
      , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Work WHERE status LIKE 'Enable' ) AS 'Enable'
      , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Work WHERE status LIKE 'Disable' ) AS 'Disable'
      , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Work WHERE status LIKE'Run') AS 'Run'
      , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Work WHERE status LIKE 'End') AS 'End'
FROM Work AS w
WHERE type ='a'
GROUP BY row,type
ORDER BY MIN(id)
```

But with this query the output is :

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | row |value | type |status |number |Enable|Disable|Run|End|
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | a   | a    |  a   |Enable | 5     | 1    | 1     | 1 | 2 |
| 2  | a   | a    |  b   |Enable | 2     | 1    | 1     | 1 | 2 |
| 3  | b   | a    |  b   |Enable | 2     | 1    | 1     | 1 | 2 |
| 4  | b   | a    |  c   |Run    | 3     | 1    | 1     | 1 | 2 |
| 5  | c   | a    |  a   |Enable | 2     | 1    | 1     | 1 | 2 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is missing `where` part in every `select count(*)...` .

`...
,(select count(*) from Work w2 where status like 'Enable' and w.row = w2.row and w.type = w2.type ) as 'Enable'
...`